# Android Fragmentation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-actionbar, android-sdk-tools

i am **confuse about android fragmentation**. I know about memory fragmentation But unable to understand that **What is android fragmentation issue**. Although i find many definitions like

> Android fragmentation refers to a concern over the alarming number of
>   different available Android operating system (OS) versions in the
>   market. The main issue is potentially reduced interoperability between
>   devices of applications coded using the Android Software Development
>   Kit (Android SDK).

Can somebody please explain this phenomenon simply. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, there are too many Android devices out there with different OS versions, screen form factors, varying hardware specs etc., all of which are expected to run every single Android app ever developed without there being any noticeable differences in performance, reliability and so on.

**Examples:**

- The `Fragment` & `ActionBar` classes were introduced in API level 11. Multiple `AsyncTask`s would run separate threads in parallel between API level 8 and 10, and serially from API level 11 onwards. This required developers to take cognizance of app behavior on different OS versions. To assist developers, Google provided support libraries that would provide newer APIs' on older platforms that did not have those features. The latest version of the support library lets you have the new `Material Design` features on older platforms.
- An app's UI needs to be uniform across tablets, phablets and handsets alike. This is why the Android framework compels developers to prepare layouts as an XML hierarchy: this is a self-scaling approach that automatically scales & positions UI elements on different screens with the correct proportion and sizing. Also, apps can display totally different UIs' depending on the screen size and OS version, and the Play Store even lets you upload different app versions for different screen sizes or different OS versions.
- Apps that have specialized hardware requirements will also not run on phones that do not have those features. Games like `Asphalt`, for instance, require a pretty powerful processor/GPU & lots of memory, and cannot run on low-end devices. Some apps require certain specific sensors, and will not even be visible in the Play Store on phones that do not have those sensors. The Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) functions were introduced on API level 17, and will not run on lower platforms.

The Android SDK is designed to help developers overcome the problem of fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a technical thing like memory fragmentation.  In this context, the word "fragmentation" refers to the changes in user experience (menu items getting moved around, etc.) and developer experience (which APIs are available, etc.) from one version of Android to the next.  Sometimes developer-facing API changes influence the user experience.  For example, a user's favorite widget might stop working on the latest version of Android because Google decided to break some API that it depends on.  Vendors and carriers make it worse with all the customizations they install, plus weird device-specific bugs.  The end result is that **there are effectively hundreds of different versions of Android** instead of just a dozen or so.  It becomes very difficult just to get an app to run on all of them, let alone provide a consistent user experience.

I don't think anyone has ever attempted to develop a metric for this kind of fragmentation, so it's hard to say whether Android is really more fragmented than other platforms.  My impression is that it is, but my standard for comparison is the J2SE API.